# How to connect two objects in C++ in order to transport data between them?

Tags: c++, class

### PROBLEM

Suppose I have a class whose objects I want to connect in some way:

```
class Object
{
  protected:
    int myValue;

  public:
    Object() : myValue(0) {}

    void SendValue() { 
    //here is some sending mechanism
    //to send my value to *all* those objects 
    //which are connected to me
    }
};
```

I want to create a connection between objects with the following requirements. Once connection was created:

1. Both ends "know" that now they are connected
2. It should be possible to send some data from one instance to another using this connection
3. This connection should not be stored many times.

The last requirement is to avoid something like this:

```
class Connection;

class Object
{
  protected:
    int myValue;
    //store all connections
    std::vector<Connection> connections;

  public:
    Object() : myValue(0) {}
    AddConnection( Connection c ) { connections.push_back(c); }
};

class Connection
{
  protected:
    const Object* in;
    const Object* out;

  public:
    Connection() : in(0), out(0) {}
    void Init( const Object* i, const Object* o ) {
      in  = i;
      out = o; 
    }
};
```

In the above example both objects must store connection between them in their `connections` variables. I know that it seems paradoxically: *Both objects should know that they are connected but should not store this connection*. Maybe it is not impossible I do not know.

### QUESTION

I **do not** ask to write the whole code for me. Just let me know what *conception* could I use.

I know the above description of the problem is not very clear so I will appreciate links to similar questions, articles etc. Or some suggestions how to edit this question in order to make it clear.

Comment: Like some kind of observer pattern that goes both ways?

Comment: I do not think that I understand what is *kind of observer pattern* but I suspect that in this case objects do not know they are connected.

Comment: This sounds like a use for `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`. Be aware that `std::shared_ptr` should be used to manage shared ownership. If there is not an ownership relationship one way or the other, then neither should have a `std::shared_ptr`, but it would be appropriate for them to have a `std::weak_ptr` where the true owner has a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: So I guess you want something like Qt's Signal and Slot or boost's signal2

Comment: You could look at some PubSub implementations for ideas.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "transport data" or "some sending mechanism"? How would an object receive data? Does it also have a `ReceiveValue()` method?

Comment: Take a look at [libsigc++](http://libsigc.sourceforge.net) and [Qt](https://www.qt.io) for two nice options.

Comment: You may find some solutions or at least inspiration by researching undirected graphs.

Comment: I believe your question has been downvoted because this is an architectural question, it is not realy C++ specific.

Answer (score -1):

There are many well known pattern to solve this problem. For exemple, the *acceptor-connector* pattern described in "Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture, vol 2"